# Get dimension length, c# arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

```
int[,] arr = new int[2,5];
var rows = arr.?
var cols = arr.?

Assert.Equals(3, rows);
Assert.Equals(6, cols);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `GetLength(some-dimension-starting-from-0)` on a array.

```
var rows = arr.GetLength(0);
var cols = arr.GetLength(1);
```

But rows will be 2 and columns 5.

```
var arr = new int[2,3]
```

Will give you:

```
arr[0,0]
arr[0,1]
arr[0,2]
arr[1,0]
arr[1,1]
arr[1,2]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use *`GetLength()`* method of array that let you know what is the length of each dimension.

```
var rows = arr.GetLength(0);
var columns = arr.GetLength(1);
```

Just to make clear, it gets the size, so in your example *rows* will be 2.

Answer (score 3):

```
arr.GetLength(dimensionYouWant);
```

Answer (score 3):

`arr.GetLength(index)`

Answer (score 0):

```
var rows = arr.GetLength(0);
var cols = arr.GetLength(1);
```